# Update: what is the structure of the copula sentence in phrase structure grammar

Tags: syntax, english, phrase-structure, copula

When it comes to the copula sentence, usually the noun phrase preceding the copula is subject.

```
(1)The problem is the kids. 
(2)??The problem are the kids. 

(3)The kids are the problem. 
(4)*The kids is the problem.
```

My question is what the differences are between (1) and (3)? Do they mean the same? What is the inner reason for such minor differences? And for equational sentences, (a subset of copular sentences), how could we draw the trees building on the framework of **phrase structure grammar**?

As Tim has pointed out,

"The aspect of the question that makes it appropriate for this forum is the fact that to answer it well, one should consider how such sentences are produced in other languages. In German, for instance, sentence (2) would have agreement with the post-copular NP, i.e. Das Problem sind /*ist die Kinder. Furthermore, the basic issue concerns the distinction between [specificational and predicational copular sentences](https://benjamins.com/catalog/la.85), areas that are of relevance to theoretical syntax. "

Thanks, @Tim for helping me clarify the questions.

Update: here is an interesting video considering this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjEi7T8hYmY

Comment: This is a question about English; not all languages have copulas, let alone copular sentences.

Comment: @jlawer thanks very much! I thought copular sentences are quite universal. Then I am wondering if you agree with the judgments. I am not very clear about that.

Comment: @jlawler. Copular sentences occur in many languages. The question is quite valid here.

Comment: @Tim To the extent that _copular sentence_ means ‘a sentence that links the subject of a sentence to a predicative expression to that subject’, I don’t think there are any languages that _don’t_ have copular sentences. They don’t all form them using copulas (e.g., Russian often uses a zero copula, Turkish uses a suffix, Classical Chinese uses the particle 也, etc.), but they all have ways of describing or assigning properties of the subject. But this question is specifically about features of _English_ copular sentences; I’d agree it’s a better fit for [english.se] than here.

Comment: @Janus. The aspect of the question that makes it appropriate for this forum is the fact that to answer it well, one should consider how such sentences are produced in other languages. In German, for instance, sentence (2) would have agreement with the post-copular NP, i.e. _Das Problem sind /*ist die Kinder_. Furthermore, the basic issue concerns the distinction between specificational and predicational copular sentences, areas that are of relevance to theoretical syntax.

Comment: I suggest that the question be expanded somewhat to mention the distinction, i.e. specificational vs. predicational copular sentences. That should give it enough linguistic weight to justify its presence in this forum.

Comment: I'd say (2) is very bad and (4) is marginal.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but in some languages like English the verb usually agrees with the initial NP, whereas with other like German it agrees with the second NP. In languages like Dutch you see free variation (as I understand it). Even in English things are not rigidly fixed. For example "All they need are a couple of votes"

Comment: I'd agree about (2) and (4). And the distinction between predicational and specificational is important. That's why plain "copular" seems like a bad term choice, because it specifies a copula.

Comment: @Tim That’s precisely the reason I would call it an English question more than a linguistics question: it is specifically asking about the restraints on the _English_ sentences, not how those restraints compare to other languages, and as asked, it is _not_ necessary to consider other languages at all to answer it well. If the question were broadened to deal with more than just the English structures specifically, I would agree with keeping it here. (Of course, the generic question about how to draw trees should also be removed.)

Comment: @Janus. The part about phrase structure in the question is crucial. Phrase structure syntax assumes a binary subject-predicate division of the clause. Specificational copular sentences are directly problematic in this area, since they are often analyzed in a manner that construes the pre-copular NP as predicative and the post-copular NP as the subject. What should the phrase structure tree in such cases look like? That is a theoretical matter that goes far beyond a simple request about how to draw the tree for a given sentence. It is not a homework question.

Comment: @Janus. But I think we can agree that the question need merely be expanded a bit to make what is at issue clearer. There would then be no hesitation about its appropriateness.

Comment: @Tim I wasn’t thinking about homework-like quality to the question, but rather that one of our close reasons is that “questions requesting syntax trees are not allowed unless they ask how a _specific grammatical feature_ can be represented in a _specific grammatical framework's syntax tree model_” – this question is arguably about a specific grammatical feature, but no framework is specified (this is why I called it a ‘generic’ tree question), so even if expanded, it might still attract close votes. **Edit:** Just realised the framework is in the title, not the body!

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments and @Tim for pointing out the further clarification which I have added to the body of the question. Many thanks!

Comment: (Just FYI: I edited the bit about marginal and bad constructions, since you had them backwards. It’s 4 that’s marginal and 2 that’s bad, not the other way around.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sorry I thought some people agree with my previous judgments on (2) and (4), for instance, Tim and jlawer. But Araucaria agrees with you. I guess those are kind of controversial.

Comment: I think John Lawler was saying that he agrees with Araucaria’s about (2) and (4), not with the way they were written in the question. And Tim was pointing out that _in German_, (2) is not only normal, but required, and (1) is ungrammatical – but only in German, not in English. To my knowledge, there is nothing controversial about (2) and (4) in English: using a singular verb with a plural subject (‘they is’) is a general feature of some dia- and sociolects, but a plural subject with a single pronoun (‘it are’) is ungrammatical everywhere (except marginally with _were_ in Northern England).

Comment: thanks for your clarification!

Comment: Here is an interesting video on this, see this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjEi7T8hYmY

Comment: Why is German even being discussed? Are we discussing all the languages of the world? Some limitation is needed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because phrase structure grammars are about syntax - patterns by which words get put together, without concern for what the resulting sentence *means* - the copula is just reflected like other verbs:

```
Sentence -> NP + Copula + AdjP
Sentence -> NP + Copula + NP
Sentence -> NP + Copula + PP
```

There is some disagreement in different kinds of phrase structure grammar. Some people treat the copula taking an NP for an object as a different type of copula, a “linking” verb, for “equational” sentences.

In some later versions of phrase structure grammars, a “movement” rule was created, where something can move to the front of the sentence, and it gets labeled with “Spec” (“specifier”), to indicate “topicalization”. For equational sentences, this seems kind of like the analogy to the “passive” voice of verbs. “The problem is Tim” could actually have Tim as the subject, “problem” as the predicate, but they’ve been inverted in a context where “the problem” is topicalized - it is in the foreground of interest, so “the problem” gets *specified* as Tim.

Arguably, there could be many kinds of copula, from a semantic perspective. You could express that A is identical to B (equative), A has the property B (predicative), A has the state B (predicative), A is a subtype of category B (also predicative), but all that are semantic relationships - the syntax of the verb remains trivial. It’s just a verb, which can take certain predicates.

Many languages express these different possible variations of the copula with differentiated words - *hen* vs. *shi*, *ser* vs. *estar*, and so on.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed illustrations! The classification of differerent kinds of copula is quite interesting! :)

Comment: Some languages have different kinds of copula from a syntactic perspective as well. There’s Chinese, which you mention, where 很 _hěn_ is an adverb but 是 _shì_ is a verb. Or Goidelic languages (Irish, Scottish, Manx), where predication (property/state) is formed with a regular verb and the normal VSO word order (`V` + `Subj[NP]` + `Pred[AdjP/PP]`); while definition (≈subtype) and equation use a copular particle and a unique word order (definition: `C` + `Pred[NP]` + `Subj[Pro]` + `(Subj[NP])`, identification: `C` + `Subj[Pro]` + `(Subj[NP])` + `Pred[NP]` + `(Subj[Pro])`).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You could post the detail answer too if you'd like. :) Thanks very much for adding it to this question!

Comment: Unfortunately, I’m not familiar enough with phrase structure grammar to be able to confidently say what the presence of multiple, different copular structures within a single language like that means for their interpretation, or how it might affect syntax trees.